# Notice: Undefined index: und in function include()

Tags: php, drupal, view

I'm getting this error: 
**Notice: Undefined index: und in function include() (line 5 in file node--view--latest-projects.tpl.php).**

the code is:

```
<li class="<?php print strip_tags(render($content['field_portfolio_category'])); ?>">
<div class="span3">
    <div class="portfolio-item thumbnail">
        <a class="thumb-info lightbox" href="#popupProject_<?php print $node->nid; ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"inline", preloader: false}'>
            <img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" alt="item">
            <span class="thumb-info-title">
              <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?php print $title; ?></span>
                <span class="thumb-info-type"><?php print strip_tags(render($content['field_portfolio_category'])); ?></span>
            </span>
            <span class="thumb-info-action">
                <span title="Universal" href="#" class="thumb-info-action-icon"><i class="icon-link"></i></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

in

Please help, as I haven't been able to define the variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these three arrays/array keys is not available `['und'][0]['uri']` in `$node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']`. To get rid of it you should do a condition:

```
<?php if(isset($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'])) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" alt="item">
<?php } ?>
```

OR figure out if one of the arrays/array keys is written wrong.

EDIT: I just noticed that you mentioned **und** in your error...so it wasn't one of the three, it was the `und` array...